# CSS fitting table into a container

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've read all advices on the topic, but non of them seems to work in my case. 
I've got this table which, as you can see, is placed in a container ('div' element):

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="../img/3.jpg"></td>
      <td colspan="3"><img src="../img/4.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><img src="../img/5.jpg"></td>
      <td><img src="../img/1.jpg"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="../img/2.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="../img/6.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

No matter what I do, I can't fix the table within div. I tried with `display: fixed`, auto widths and all. it just stubbornly 'spills out' all over the place. 

Not sure what I am doing wrong. CSS for container, which is just a perfect amount of space to fit it on my website, is as follow:

```
.container {
display: inline-block;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per request I am updating full code of mentioned website:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Reflexiones</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/inicio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/reflexiones.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/comun.css">
  <body>
  </body>
  <section class="caja">
    <nav class="strip" id="s_top">
      <a id="line" href="index.html">INICIO</a>
      <a id="line" href="audio.html">AUDIO</a>
      <a id="line" href="video.html">VIDEOS</a>
      <a id="line" class="bold" href="reflexiones.html">REFLEXIONES</a>
      <a href="contactar.html">CONTACTAR</a>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <p>
        El 75% de la flora silvestre se poliniza gracias a las abejas y casi el 40% de las frutas y verduras que comemos procede de la polinización, que realizan estos insectos en declive por un "cóctel" de amenazas como los plaguicidas, transgénicos, el ácaro varroa, e incluso la mala acción de apicultores inexpertos. <br>
        Así lo han expresado diversos expertos consultados, que han coincidido en destacar que estos insectos, a menudo molestos, para los habitantes de las ciudades son imprescindibles para la vida. 
      </p>
      <p>
        Varios factores, entre los que destacan la climatología adversa y el uso de pesticidas prohibidos en otros países de nuestro entorno, han ocasionado en España una fuerte mortandad de las abejas. Además de las pérdidas en la producción de miel y otros productos apícolas, la principal consecuencia de esta fuerte reducción del número de abejas es la escasa polinización tanto de cultivos como de especies silvestres, lo que tiene nefastas repercusiones económicas en muchos cultivos y en cuanto a la biodiversidad de nuestros montes.
      </p>
      <p>
        En 1999 un estudio sobre la producción de miel de girasol en el oeste de Francia realizado por la Cooperativa France Miel, mostró una caída del 50% en la producción de este tipo de miel desde el año 1994. Este descenso coincide con la puesta en el mercado del insecticida sistémico Gaucho, en 1993, cuya molécula activa es el imidacloprid, que se usaba para el tratamiento de semillas de girasol y maíz. Tras su prohibición en 1999 fue sustituido por el producto comercial Regent cuya molécula activa es el fipronil. Este descenso de producción se acrecentó con el aumento de las superficies tratadas.
      </p>
      <div class="container">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="../img/3.jpg"></td>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="../img/4.jpg"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="../img/5.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="../img/1.jpg"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"><img src="../img/2.jpg"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="../img/6.jpg"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="strip" id="s_bottom">
      <a id="line" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
      <a id="line" href="audio.html">Audio</a>
      <a id="line" href="video.html">Videos</a>
      <a id="line" class="bold" href="reflexiones.html">Reflexiones</a>
      <a href="contactar.html">Contactar</a>
    </footer>
  </section>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

CSS, for table/container:

since posting I've added 'overflow: auto;' property to 'container' class. Getting there. I think I'll just ad some id's to content and sort the rest this way.

```
.container {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

table {

    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td {

    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0px;

}

table img {

    margin: 0px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;

}
```

Comment: A `table` will always be as wide and as high as its content makes it. There's nothing you can do about it. That being said, your `table` also is invalid because each  `tr` must contain exactly the same number of cells (unless you replace some `td` using `colspan`, yet the sum of cols must be identical per row).

Comment: basically what you are suggesting is that I manipulate with the size of the pictures within the table?

Comment: Why are you using a table at all here? This does not look like tabular data - which is the only thing you would ever use a `table` for. **`tables` must not be used for layout purposes.**

Comment: I understand, and it's not for layout purposes. If it was up to me I would not use table at all, but it's not up to me and I need table to fit that tiny space which is refusing to do. It spills out beyond it's own container and container containing that container. Really nasty stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Actually without a code snippet I can only guess what's going on. But I think you mean that the table is higher than the div and overlaps it.

So maybe you are done if you remove the height from the container like this:

```
.container {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 400px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

BTW *display: fixed* doesn't exist.

If the code above doesn't work then please provide a working code snippet (with jsfiddle for example) or a link to a live website.

Comment: display: fixed,doesn't exist but table-layout: fixed; does, and that's what I've tried. If I remove height from container than it does not change the fact that table is way too big for the space I've got for it which is 400x200px

Comment: As I stated in my answer without a working code snippet or link I can only guess what you mean. What does "too big" mean? Too wide or too high? Sorry but I can't advice more if I don't see the code. You can make a code sample at https://jsfiddle.net, save the snippet and post the link here.

Comment: OK, I'll update full website's code. Will that help? No worries it's a very short code. For practise purposes. Not comertial.

Comment: The problem remains the same, I can't see what's in your CSS files :) Please make a Fiddle with only the container and table HTML/CSS snippets.

Comment: For the table you have defined a larger width (600px) than for the container (400px). Sure the table can't fit into the container.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why did you define 600px for the table and 400px for the container? Also - you did not explain what really doesn't work, did not provide a Fiddle and not answer my questions clearly that I asked in my comments. If you don't do this I will be out of this thread and nothing post anymore. Thanks!

Comment: All sorted now. I did, define it like that, because otherwise it would crump everything together. But than after closing the browser and starting thing on again happened what you said. The table was too long (even though it would display it fine before, no idea why is it doing it to me) so adjusted that and it works fine. I maen all is where it supposed to be. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The only options I see here is to *either* make the rest of the table available by scrolling the container (`overflow: auto;` on the container) *or* applying `transform: scale(0.3);` on the `table` (You'll have to try and find the factor that makes it fit exactly).

And, as I already said before, fix the number of cols per row. They must be identical on all rows.

Comment: Thanks, it did not solve the problem completly, but it helped a great deal. I think I can take it from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your input. In the end got it sorted by manipulating the content and setting all the padding and margines to 0.